# MailJet | how to Send Mail with Python using variables in text part?

Tags: python, mailjet

I want to add "print (variable_name)" to the following statement:

'Text-part': 'Dear passenger, welcome to Mailjet! May the delivery force be with you!',

How can it be done?

Following is the Python code:

```
from mailjet_rest import Client
import os

data = {
        'FromEmail': '****@****.com',
        'FromName': '****',
        'Subject': 'Available DB Names:', #Subject
        'Text-part': 'Dear passenger, welcome to Mailjet! May the delivery 
         force be with you!',
         'Recipients': [{ "Email": "****@****.com"}]
          }
         result = mailjet.send.create(data=data)
         print (result.status_code)
         print (result.json())
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something like this?

```
data = {
        'FromEmail': '****@****.com',
        'FromName': '****',
        'Subject': 'Available DB Names:', #Subject
        'Text-part': 'Dear {}, welcome to Mailjet! May the delivery 
         force be with you!'.format(variable_name),
         'Recipients': [{ "Email": "****@****.com"}]
          }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, correct, finally worte following and it worked for me:

 'Text-part': 'Dear {}, welcome to Mailjet! May the delivery '  + str(variable_name)

Comment: @Josh Friedlander why do you cast to `str()` before passing into `format()`? You're ruining all the goodness that `format()` has to offer!

Comment: @NilsWerner thanks for pointing that out. As you'll see in the edit history, my original answer didn't include `str` - not sure why I changed it, but I've reverted it now...

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to also declare your `vars` section within the call. That is were you would give a value to your custom variables.

```
"Variables": {
                                "day": "Monday"
                        }
```

And the placeholder within the HTML-Part or Text-Part would look as such `{{var:day}}` which would be replaced by the value of your custom variable at the recipients end.